# Having two different files display their hash keys on the command line and comparing them using Perl

Tags: perl, hash

I am having difficulty having this program run. .

The first set of code reads from a file that contains data that looks like this:

```
>name
AGCTGCA
```

The second set of code reads from a file that contains data that looks like this:

```
>name 0.05
```

My Perl code

```
my %sequence_of;
open(INPUT, $ARGV[0]) or die "Cannot open the file: $!";
my $hash_key;

my $hash_value;
while (my $line = <INPUT>) {
   if ($line =~ /^>(\S+)/) {
      $hash_key = $1;
   }

   elsif ($line =~ /\S/) {
      chomp $line;
      $hash_value = $line;
      $sequence_of{$hash_key} = $hash_value;
   } 
}

foreach my $hash_key2 (keys %sequence_of) {
   print "$hash_key2\t$sequence_of{$hash_key2}\n";
}

#open the second file
my %name_of;
open(INPUT_2, $ARGV[1]) or die "Cannot open the file: $!";
my $hash_key_2;
my $hash_value_2;

while (my $line = <INPUT_2>) {
   if ($line =~ /^>(\S+)/) {
      $hash_key_2 = $1;
   }
   elsif ($line =~ /\S/) {
      chomp $line;
      $hash_value_2 = $line;
      $name_of{$hash_key_2} = $hash_value_2;
   } 
}

foreach my $hash_key_3 (keys %name_of) {
   print "$hash_key_3\t$name_of{$hash_key_3}\n";
}
```

The second part is the one giving me issues. I know there are no syntax errors because it lets me run it, but the second part doesn't print anything.

Comment: I apologize for the formatting, new to this website and it didn't let me post it how I had it typed.

Comment: I've edited your post for formatting.  Editing help is available (albeit not very obvious) as a `?` at the right-hand side of the toolbar above the edit area (assuming that you have Javascript enabled for Stack Overflow).  There's also [a full help page](/editing-help) that should teach you what you need.

Comment: Put a `print $1;` in the `if` statement before assigning it to `$hash_key_2`, and put a `print $line;` inside of the `elsif` statement to see if you're actually catching on your regex checks. Using `$1` is better written in an assignment something like: `$var = $1 || 0;` or similar, as if `$1` is undef, it'll proceed silently. I'm not saying that's your problem (especially without knowing your input data), but it's pretty common.

Comment: @DrG: I have edited your question to show what I think is the contents of your data file. (I guess they're FASTA files?) Please confirm that it's correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your program does is to open two files, read them into hashes and dump them

From your question I suspect that your second file is just a series of headers without any data. If so then that is why your second file shows no output -- because there isn't any

A wild guess says that you want to look up the sequences from the first file using the keys in the second file. You're simply looking in the wrong hash, and you can fix that by changing your penultimate line to

```
print "$hash_key_3\t$sequenceof{$hash_key_3}\n";
```

---

#### Update

Here's how I would solve your problem. There's no need to store the contents of the second hash in memory -- you can just pick out the IDs and look up the sequences as you read through the file

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ( $repmod_file, $evalues_file ) = @ARGV;

my %sequence;
{
    open my $fh, '<', $repmod_file
        or die qq{Unable to open "$repmod_file": $!};

    my $key;
    while ( <$fh> ) {
        if ( /^>(\S+)/ ) {
            $key = $1;
        }
        elsif ( /\S/ ) {
            chomp;
            $sequence{$key} .= $_;
        }
    }
}

open my $fh, '<', $evalues_file
    or die qq{Unable to open "$evalues_file": $!};
while ( <$fh> ) {
    if ( /^>(\S+)/ ) {
        printf "%s\t%s\n", $1, $sequence{$1} // 'undef';
    }
}
```

Comment: how i would go about doing that? would if then work in this scenario?

Comment: I thought I'd explained that. What don't you understand?

Comment: @DrG: Please confirm that I'm right about what you're trying to do, as it doesn't really square with your subject line

Comment: trying to up your answer for your time but it is not letting me. sorry. thanks again.

Comment: i dont think i worded as correctly as i could have.

Comment: @DrG: Don't worry about that: I have no interest in votes. But if one of the answers has solved your problem then you should accept it so that others can see that it has been resolved